# Clearing a text input (if it's empty) when another text box is clicked - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an email text box that contains the text '(Not Required)' until a user clicks on it, at which point it turns blank. I'm trying to make it to where if the user clicks another text box without entering an email address (or entering anything), the text box will revert to containing (Not Required).

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#email').val("(Not Required)");

   // this part works fine
   $('#email').click(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == '(Not Required)'){
           $(this).val('');
       }
   });

   // this isn't working
   $(':text').click(function(){
       var em = $('#email').val().length();
       if (em<3){
           $('#email').val('(Not Required)');
       }
   });

});
```

I can't figure out why the second part isn't working correctly. Any help would be rewarded with a lifetime's devotion to yourself from myself in a very big way. Forever.

Comment: You used `val()` in the first part to get the contents of the text box. Try using that in the second part too, instead of `text()`.

Comment: use jquery watermark plugin instead of reinventing the wheel. try this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

Comment: I switched to val() with no success =(

Comment: Try `.val().length` (i.e. `length` isn't a function, but a property).

Comment: see my answer for better jquery use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var em = $('#email').text().length();
```

Should be

```
var em = $('#email').val().length;
```

And I show you a better way do this by chain method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#email').val("(Not Required)").foucs(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length < 3 ){
           $(this).val('(Not Required)');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @gdoron It's a typo :) fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$('#email').val().length` instead of `$('#email').text().length()`

Comment: That's actually what I was trying before I switched it to .text().length()    --- I switched back to .val().length() but it's still not working

Comment: @Drake Ruppert  There is also a property length, not a function length(). Check the answer of xdazz.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#email').text().length();
```

to

```
$('#email').val().length;
```

And just a suggestion, why not use the blur() event of the email input to return the 'Not Required' text instead of waiting for a click on another input box?

Comment: +1 for the blur suggestion. (And note, Drake, that focus would be better than click for removing "Not Required" - always allow for keyboard navigation.)

Answer (score 0):

- `click` isn't the event you should catch. `focus` is the one to go. never forget keyboard navigation.
- Don't query the DOM twice, save the DOM element and work with it.
- use `val()` instead of `text` and length instead od `length()`
- `:text` isn't a good selector. it implies the global selector `$('*')`

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $email = $('#email');
    $email.val("(Not Required)");

   // this part works fine
   $email.focus(function(){
       if (this.value == '(Not Required)'){
           this.value ='';
       }
   });

   $('#otherTextBoxId').focus(function(){
       if ($email.val().length <3 ){
           $email.val('(Not Required)');
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works much better. I would upvote but I'm unable to do so--I just registered.

Comment: So why query `$('#email')` three times and use `$(this)` twice? :)

Comment: @xdazz. busted... That code I copied from the question without looking at it too much,fixed thanks...

Comment: @gdoron You are still query `$('#email')` every time when focus on `$('#otherTextBoxId')`, you should just put ` var $email = $('#email');` outside.